# How can I highlight dates in cells with excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, comparison, cell, highlight

please help.
I have to column of dates (column I and R).
I need to highlight the date in column I, if both dates are older than today's date.

Thanks in advance!

Mike

Comment: Why not use Conditional Formatting?

Comment: If you do want to use VBA, please show what you have tried and tell us why it isn't working.  (The code required is fairly simple - a loop, an `If` statement, an `And` operator, the function `Now`, and something to colour or otherwise highlight the cells - all very easily googled.)

Comment: Hi, I thought it was very easy..googled..have been trying for hours. I cant even get it to a point to mark the dates in one column.Here is what I have:
Dim example As Range
Set example = Range("H1:H1000")
If example.Value < Date Then example.Font.Color = vbRed

Comment: Maybe one more...It works for one cell with this simple code:
If Range("H2").Value < Date Then Range("H2").Font.ColorIndex = 3
But I can't make it work for the entire colum. If I replace "H2" with e.g. "H2:H1000" it wont work :-(

Comment: You can't do array operations (such as `Range("H2:H1000").Value < Date`) in VBA.  That's why you will need a loop.  And, once you set up your loop (perhaps a `For r = 2 To 1000` loop), within it you would test whether `Range("H" & r).Value < Date`.  But if that hint doesn't help you get further and **IF** you update the question with some code (not just include it in comments) then I will help you finish it off.  (Just ping me - i.e. write a comment with an `@YowE3K` in it - to let me know if/when you have updated the question.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Since I am new in this portal and also to Excel VBA, maybe you can simply send me the code?
Here is what I need to achieve: I have dates in column H. I need to mark the dates in red, that are in the past. The help would be much appreciated.